# find multiple (2) elements in a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, indexing, element

I want to return whether one of the conditions exist within findAB(str) as boolean

1. A 5 letter long string which starts with 'a' ends with 'b'
2. A 5 letter long string which starts with 'b' ends with 'a'

```
function findAB(str) {

  let lowerSTR = str.toLowerCase()
  let indexOFa = lowerSTR.indexOf('a')
  let indexOFb = lowerSTR.indexOf('b')

  if (lowerSTR[indexOFa + 4] === 'b' || lowerSTR[indexOFb + 4] === 'a') {
    return true;
  } 
    return false;

}
```

I first changed strings into lower case using `.toLowerCase()` method and defined `indexOFa` and `indexOFb`.

I thought simply by doing index of `a + 4` will turn out true but in fact it doesn't and cannot figure out what I did wrong.
I also know some method to find elements in an array such as find(), includes(), map() or filter but not sure if I can use it since it is not an array.

Comment: While doing this with the tools you are using works, Regex is your friend here.

Comment: That being said, one problem is, that you don't deal with there not being any "a" or "b". `indexOf` returns `-1` in that case, and e.g. "dfsa" would have an "a" at index `-1 + 4`.

Comment: use this regex ```/(.?(((a|A)[a-zA-Z]{3}(b|B))|((b|B)[a-zA-Z]{3}(a|A))).?)/```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search for a pattern of 5 characters which starts and ends with (a and b) or (b and a) irrespective of case and any length of string, you can do something like this.
The regex considers that the string "a _ _ _ b" or "b _ _ _ a" can have only alphabets in any case not any other character, if you are accepting any other character you can update [a-zA-Z] part in the regex.

```
function findAB(str) {
  const regexp = /(.?(((a|A)[a-zA-Z]{3}(b|B))|((b|B)[a-zA-Z]{3}(a|A))).?)/;
  return regexp.test(str);
}
```

If it is fixed that length of string should be 5 and you are just dealing with first and last character you can simply use the following function

```
function findAB(str) {
  const lengthOfString = str.length;
  
  if (lengthOfString === 5) {
    const firstCharacter = str[0].toLowerCase()
    const lastCharacter = str[lengthOfString-1].toLowerCase()
    
    return (firstCharacter === 'a' && lastCharacter === 'b') || (firstCharacter === 'b' && lastCharacter === 'a');
  }
  
  // returns false string does not contains 5 characters
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change your approach you can use regex like this

```
function findAB(str) {

  let case1 = str.match(/a[a-z]*b/g); // get all substrings starting with a and ending with b
  let case2 = str.match(/b[a-z]*a/g); // get all substrings starting with b and ending with a

  case1.forEach((matchedString) => {
    if (matchedString.length == 5) {
      return true;
    }
  });

  case2.forEach((matchedString) => {
    if (matchedString.length == 5) {
      return true;
    }
  });

  return false; // return false if no substrings matching condition exists
}
```

If you need to tell the difference between which case was triggered this could be a cleaner solution to read.

Comment: `/a.{3}b/i.test(str) || /b.{3}a/i.test(str)`... if there are newlines and whatnot, maybe a dotall flag or related for older browsers would be needed.

Comment: Probably for just three symbols, just using `...` instead of `.{3}` would even improve readability. Just don't get to a point, where a reader has to start counting dots.

Answer (score 0):

**Correcting your solution.**

The problem with your solution is that `indexOf` returns `-1` if the no match is found. So `findAB("bbbbb")` will return `true`, because `indexOFa` variable will be equal to `-1` and `lowerSTR[indexOFa + 4]` will check the second last character and the condition will evaluate to `true`. So the following code will solve your problem.

```
function findAB(str) {

  let lowerSTR = str.toLowerCase()
  let indexOFa = lowerSTR.indexOf('a')
  let indexOFb = lowerSTR.indexOf('b')

  if ((indexOFa >= 0 && lowerSTR[indexOFa + 4] === 'b') || (indexOFb >= 0 && lowerSTR[indexOFb + 4] === 'a')) {
    return true;
  } 
    return false;

}
```

Also, I wouldn't prefer hardcoding `4` better use `str.length-1`.

You could also just simply do it like this

```
function findAB(str) {
  let lowerSTR = str.toLowerCase();
  let indexOFa = lowerSTR.indexOf('a');
  let indexOFb = lowerSTR.indexOf('b');

  if (
    (indexOFa === 0 && indexOFb === str.length - 1) ||
    (indexOFb === 0 && indexOFa === str.length - 1)
  )
    return true;
  return false;
}
```